# fitting linear regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2

It might sound like a stupid question, but I can not see my error here...

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,100) + rnorm(100),
                 y=seq(1,100) + rnorm(100,10,5))
reg_coeff <- lm(df$x ~ df$y)$coefficients
my_env <- environment()
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept=reg_coeff[[1]],
              slope=reg_coeff[[2]])
```

Why is the fitting of the line not correct? It is miles away from the points...

I am confused... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you are estimating `x ~ y` but plotting the regression line for `y ~ x`.  Change your code to `reg_coeff <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)$coefficients`

Comment: Hi you can use this : **ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +   geom_point() +stat_smooth( method="lm", formula=y~x)** this is similar

Comment: Thank you both! That was the error I didn't realised... Maybe I should make break! :-)